# How to convert from shape into polygon in R? There was shape2poly(shapefiles) but this function have been removed

Tags: r, package, shapefile, cran

How to convert from shape into polygon in R? There was `shape2poly(shapefiles)` but this function have been removed, are `shapefiles`, `maptools`, `spdep` still packages for handling maps in R?

Comment: Maybe this : `library(maptools);my.shapefile <- read.shape("shapefile.shp")` can help you?

Comment: @agstudy `Error: could not find function "read.shape"`, so your function is outdated as my  shape2poly(shapefiles)

Comment: it is not mine :) looks like convert a shape to a polygon is has-been habit :)

Comment: If you give us a description of your ultimate goal - do you want to plot a map, for example? - the chances of you getting a useful answer will be much higher. If you want to plot a map, the answer below shows you how to read a shapefile and [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655230/how-do-you-combine-a-map-with-complex-display-of-points-in-ggplot2/13655715#13655715) on this site show you how to plot a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use the OGR stuff, as it lets me work with data from a range of sources (geodatabases, kml, etc).

```
library(rgdal)
mylayer <- readOGR(dsn="/path/to/folder/containing/shapefile",
                   layer="shapefilename-minus-dot-shp")
```