# R - using data of shapefiles/SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to colour/fill ggplots

Tags: r, attributes, ggplot2, shapefile

I have a specific question: How can I choose either fill or color of a ggplot according to the data of an SpatialPolygonsDataFrame-object? For example consider the following SpatialPolygonsDataFrame sf:

```
sf <- readShapePoly("somePolygonShapeFile")
```

It allows me to access the the example data field FK like:

```
sf$FK            // or
sf@data$FK
```

Now, I want to prepare a simple ggplot:

```
p <- ggplot(sf, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, FK=???))
```

However, I don't know what to pass to FK in aes(). Experiences from gridded data frames (grid.extent(...)) made me think, I could directly put in FK=FK. This does not seem to work for SpatialPolygonsDataFrame-objects. Trying FK=sf$FK or FK=sf@data$FK is not allowed because:

```
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the data
```

I guess, the solution is trivial, but I simply don't get it at the moment.

Comment: Maybe take a look here : https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles

Comment: @juba I've tried to be as close to the tutorial code as possible. However, utah.points = fortify(utah, region="id") only returns an error: `isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE`

Comment: just type `gpclibPermit()` or install the `rgeos` package. The `gpclibPermit` function is used to choose to permit the use of `gpclib` if installed, and `gpclibPermitStatus` reports its status. The licence for `gpclib` is not Free or Open Source and explicitly forbids commercial use.

Comment: @rcs Finally the crux. I hadn't installed gpclib and wasn't able to give me gpclibPermit as a result. Now I can fortify using a region. Hopefully the manual descriptions ([link](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles)) work for me as well now, so that I can easily transfer the shapefile data field content into the dataframe. Thank you for mentioning the requirements explicitly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @juba, @rsc and @SlowLearner I've found out, that the installation of gpclib was still missing to be able to give the gpclibPermit. With this done, fortifying `sf` using a specified region is not problem anymore. Using the explanation from [ggplot2/wiki](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles) I am able to transfer all data fields of the original shapefile into a plotting-friendly dataframe. The latter finally works as was intendet for plotting the shapefile in R. Here is the final code with the actual workingDir-variable content left out:

```
require("rgdal") # requires sp, will use proj.4 if installed
require("maptools")
require("ggplot2")
require("plyr")

workingDir <- ""

sf <- readOGR(dsn=workingDir, layer="BK50_Ausschnitt005")
sf@data$id <- rownames(sf@data)
sf.points <- fortify(sf, region="id")
sf.df <- join(sf.points, sf@data, by="id")

ggplot(sf.df,aes(x=long, y=lat, fill=NFK)) + coord_equal() + geom_polygon(colour="black", size=0.1, aes(group=group))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use the `readOGR` function from the `rgdal` library to read your shapefile (then you won't have problems with `gpclib`). Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757281/r-map-switzerland-according-to-npa-locality/18092284#18092284) of how to do that.

Second, are you trying to pass the `sf` object to `ggplot` as-is? If so, you need to use `fortify()` to convert your spatial object into a data frame. There should be some kind of identifying column in `sf@data` such as `ID` or `NAME`. So try something like:

```
sf.df <- fortify(df, region = "NAME")
```

...and use `sf.df` for plotting using `ggplot`.

Comment: Your answer and the cited example helped understanding the context better. I still needed to join the indivual points of the polygon by the previously created polygon ids as referenced in the comment of @juba in the first post. Still, you have my thanks.